# Как заставить fprintf писать дробные через точку?

Tags: windows, c

Здравствуйте!

Как заставить fprintf писать дробные через точку? В Windows пишет через запятую. Менять в настройках винды не подходит. Обрабатывать весь файл тоже не подходит.
Язык программирования Си.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно записывать отдельно целую, отдельно дробную часть?

Comment: @avp, работает, спасибо.  
Оформите как ответ, выберу верным.  
СПАСИБО!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ВладиславМСК](/users/4878/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA), может быть

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

и в винде сработает?